# Вывести из базы информацию в ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Меняю вопрос в корне, как мне вывести данные в лист вью что бы каждое поле было отдельно? вывожу вот таким способом, но информация вся хранится в одной строчке листВью.

```
    public class RequestHistoryListActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history_database_request);
        DatabaseOpenHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] from = { HistoryColumns.REQUEST, BaseColumns._ID };
        final Cursor c = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, null);
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list, c,
                from, to);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                // c.moveToPosition(pos);
                int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
                // Uri outURI = Uri.parse(data.toString() + rowId);
                /*
                 * Intent outData = new Intent(); History oneRow = new History();
                 * oneRow.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID)));
                 * oneRow.setRequest(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryColumns.REQUEST)));
                 * setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, outData); finish();
                 */
                Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, rowId);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

history_database_request.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

и то во что выводим

lisr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This is text1"
      android:textSize="25dip" />      
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter не подходит? Либо делать кастомный CursorAdapter. В вашем коде не вижу где вы биндите на ListView данные

Comment: hm.put(BOOKKEY, readHistory(getBaseContext()).toString()); вот эта строчка

Comment: Если честно впервые вижу, чтобы из курсора в ArrayList перегоняли и передавали как параметр в SimpleAdapter

В CursorAdapter (SimpleCursorAdapter в частности) один из параметров при OnItemClick событии как раз нужный id (с ним сделать нужный Uri не сложно)

Comment: можете подправить пожалуйста, я без понятия что делать, и то что Вы написали мне с трудом доходит

Comment: @rasmisha, а в чем разница? просто так у меня так же ничего не выводится

Comment: Да вот сам пытаюсь понять в чем проблема. У меня просто бывало не выводилось тоже когда TextView был в контейнере, а использовал SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Оп, починил все, работает! Не знаю как криом как-то но работает) Теперь нужно понять как передать айдишник по которому кликнули и вывести нужные данные. Можете помочь?

Comment: Да айдишник есть

> OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Унаследуйтесь от AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
И 

> listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Создавать примерно так

```
Cursor cursor = getCursor() // любой метод возвращающий курсор
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
   this,
   R.layout.[layout_name], // ваш лэйаут, можно взять стандартный из android.R
   new String[] { DBMetaData.FirstFieldName, DBMetaData.SecondFieldName }, // имена полей
   new int[] { R.id.tvFirstField, R.id.tvSecondField } // id текствьюх в выбранном лэйауте
);
```

Comment: Я не понял про любой метод возвращающий курсор, что это за метод? Самописный? Или какой-то определенный?

Comment: может быть как самописный 

так и getContentResolver().managaQuery(...), например

Главное чтобы нужные поля были

т.е. на этой строчке можно было бы остановиться 

> Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, columnsToTake, 
> null, null, null, null,
>                    History.DEFAULT_SORT);

Comment: Написал как у Вас, поля отобразилась все, а данные в них нет, поля пустые, что это может быть? http://imm.io/pJfI

Comment: чего-то в голову не приходит. Не черный текст на черном?) В базе точно что-то есть? (можете пробежаться по курсору значение в лог повыводить)

Comment: когда вывожу в лог выводит все как нужно, а тут пусто, поля в xml у меня белым выделены, так что должно отображать нормально...

Comment: а могли бы показать xml и строчку конструктор адаптера?

Comment: @rasmisha, добавил код который сейчас юзаю и xml

Comment: Попробуйте заменить
> android:id="@+id/text1"
на
> android:id="@android:id/text1"

Ну и соответственно в коде тоже на android.R.id.text1

И еще зачем вам нужные LinearLayout (тем более 2)

Можно же корнем сделать TextView (раз он один).

Answer (score 4):

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    list = new ArrayList<History>();
                }
```

передвигаешь курсор на начало - так делать не надо, лучше проверить курсов на нул...

```
 for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

заменить на

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

---

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(History.TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "count(*)" }, null, null, null,
            null, History.DEFAULT_SORT);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        countRows = cursor.getInt(0);
        if (LOGV) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Count in history table" + String.valueOf(countRows));
        }
```

вообще все лишнее, Count  можно проверить посмотрев размер курсора.

```
oneRow.setRequest(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HistoryColumns.REQUEST)));
```

тут ты сеттеш поле HistoryColumns.REQUEST в oneRow объект

потом надо сделать, чтото типа

```
String str = oneRow.getRequest();
```

собрать все это в массив и передать в листАдаптер - все отобразится... то я не думаю, что это решит твою задачу

Comment: Спасибо, а по вопросу можно что нибудь подсказать? Как мне вывести колонку Request в ListView ?

Comment: @dajver не дает писать нигде) напишу тут.

Почему 

> int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));

а не

> rowId = (int)id;

и разве в лог выводятся нормально числовые типы?

Comment: ниче не дает, мне не понятно как передать айдишник...

Comment: long id в методе должен быть равен id в базе для выбранного элемента

Comment: У меня стоит задача, передать айдишник и вывести в эдит текст из таблицы данные которые храняться по этому айдишнику

Comment: Ну дак и сформируйте Uri

> content://your.application/history/[id]

И в запрос отправляйте, и считывайте нужные Вам данные

Либо запрос с условием BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id

Comment: Мне не понятно как принимать на второй активити этот айдишник

Comment: @dajver intent.setData(Uri uri) есть же 

В принимающем активити getIntent().getData()